# Laravel : Socialite steam redirected but not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I would like to add "Login with steam" option on my Laravel 10 app.
I'm using [Socialite - Steam](https://socialiteproviders.com/Steam).

I have added the following in my `config/services.php`

```
    'steam' => [
        'client_id' => null,
        'client_secret' => env('STEAM_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('STEAM_REDIRECT_URI'),
        /*'allowed_hosts' => [
            env('APP_DOMAIN'),
        ]*/
    ],
```

And in my `.env` I have add :

```
APP_DOMAIN=localhost
STEAM_CLIENT_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
STEAM_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:8000/auth/redirect
```

With my steam API key domain defined to `localhost`.

When I navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/redirect, i'm redirected to steam login page correctly but once I press "Login" I got the message "Error" without further explains as the screenshot below
[Steam login page with error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ2Vj.png)

If I use the `allowed_hosts` configured with `localhost` in my `config/services.php`, I don't have the error but the steam login page is just refreshed.

If you guys have any ideas on why it's not working, I haven't found anything online about this.

Thanks

Comment: Oauth can work with localhost. I think problem is in steam client config - you need specify localhost as permitted redirect adress. And i think this it is writen on the error page, but you post non english text to english resource (why?..)